# Ejecutar aplicación Python sin modo Administrador

Tags: python, sqlite, ejecutar

He creado una aplicación con Python 3.6 y la librería gráfica Tkinter. La aplicación funciona con la librería Sqlite para gestionar un apartado que necesita guardarse en memoria cada vez que se use la aplicación para que al volver a arrancarla los datos sigan ahí. El problema es que cuando genero un ejecutable con PYINSTALLER e instalo mi aplicación en el disco duro, es necesario ejecutarla con permisos de administrador si no no puede 'escribir' en el disco duro y los cambios que hago no se reflejan. Si ejecuto en modo administrador funciona bien. Mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo hacer para que funcione sin necesidad de ejecutar en modo administrador?

No puedo adjuntar código por temas de confidencialidad. Un saludo y gracias.

**EDICION RUTA**
El archivo de base de datos esta en la siguiente ruta:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_Name\database
```

En esa ruta está una vez que he instalado la aplicación en mi PC.

Resultado de ejecutar dir /Q para ver el propietario de cada archivo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres decir que utilice otra ruta que no esté en C:/ ??

Comment: Disculpa pero no se como funciona el chat. No sabia ni siquiera que hubiera un chat.

Comment: ¡ jajajaj ! nada hombre, lo usamos para charla informal. *Pincha* en el enlace y debería de aparecer allí ¡ Ah pues no ! Un momento ...

Comment: Me dice que necesito 20 de reputación :(

Comment: ¡ Pero si tienes 109 !  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol